# How do I Use Rating bar and Edit text values together

Tags: android, android-edittext, ratingbar

I am trying to get the rating bar values to multiply times the values in edittext and display that in the amount variable but I cant seem to get anything to work? I have tried searching for something but all I could get was how to get the edittext on the screen or how to get the rating value on the screen but not combined. Sorry I'm new to this.

```
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RatingBar;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private RatingBar ratingBar;
private TextView amount;
private EditText edittext;
int a = Integer.parseInt(edittext.getText().toString());
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    addListenerOnRatingBar();
    edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    final String rec = edittext.getText().toString();


}

public void addListenerOnRatingBar() {

    ratingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
    amount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.amount);

    ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() {

        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {

            String tellthem = ;


        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you update the title so it describes the question you're asking. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Complete. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You just add following code on `onRatingChanged(...)` method :

```
public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {

 String editTextValue = edittext.getText();
 double ratingValue = rating * Double.valueOf(editTextValue);
 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "rating:"+String.valueOf(ratingValue),
  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set text in textview at `setOnRatingBarChangeListener()`.

```
 ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() {

        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {

            String edtValue = edittext.getText().toString();
            double ratingValue = rating * Double.valueOf(edtValue);
            amount.setText(String.valueOf(ratingValue));
        }
    });
```